# UDF Partition reported full when it is not

Tags: partitioning, udf

I was using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/27950/11736) to setup an external hard disk with udf. I have been able to setup a multi-partition system using those instructions, but I seem to have hit a wall, where the partition is reported as full while writing to the disk. Every other tool available to me reports it as free.

- [Relevant lshw output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1182768/)

Here's a screenshot showing the disk:

[image: Screenshot of disk-utility tool]

Both the output of `df` and the file manager (`caja`) report the disk as free.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9       9.0G  7.6G  910M  90% /
udev            974M   12K  974M   1% /dev
/dev/sda1        50G   47G  295M 100% /media/Data
/dev/sda6        49G   41G  5.9G  88% /home
/dev/sda2       155G  127G   29G  82% /media/Entertainment
/dev/sda8        14G   13G  516M  96% /media/Stuff
/dev/sdb2       120G  1.9G  112G   2% /media/3c887659-5676-4946-875b-b797be508ce7
/dev/sdb3        11G  2.6G  7.7G  25% /media/108b0a1d-fd1a-4f38-b1c6-4ad1a20e34a3
/dev/sdb1       802G   34G  768G   5% /media/disk
```

I seem to have hit a wall near the 35GB mark. Despite being shown as 35gb/860gb used everywhere, the following happens on a write attempt:

```
[2017][/media/Dory]$ echo D>>echo
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

Writing byte by byte, the maximum I can take it to is `34719248K`.

The most weird part is that on mounting it Windows, Windows can write to the disk easily, and the writes are being read fine back in Ubuntu. However, the used-bytes remains at `34719248K` in Ubuntu (It goes higher on Windows, however).

Answer (score 0):

This is a kernel bug (53021) which has a patch, but the patch has only been committed (as far as I can tell) to current, not any stable or longterm branch. It applies cleanly to 3.2 and later kernels at a minimum; there is an Ubuntu bug (583949) which currently requests that the patch be backported to quantal (3.5.x) and raring (3.8.x).